# How to load list.js dynamically through ajax and for sort to continue working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a static HTML page which loads dynamic tables using Ajax. The tables I want to load are sortable tables built using list.js and jQuery. When the tables are coded in line they load and are sortable without issue. As soon as I introduce Ajax, the data appears but sorting no longer works.

I am aware of binding and .on() but I am not sure how to get it working with list.js

Example Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"
src="//listjs.com/js/list.js"

$(document).ready(function(){

// Define value names
var overview_options = { valueNames: [ 'name', 'term', 'module', 'activity' ] };

// Init list
var overviewList = new List('list_overview', overview_options);

});

function loadTable() {

getTable=new XMLHttpRequest();
getTable.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (getTable.readyState==4 && getTable.status==200)
    {
            document.getElementById("tableArea").innerHTML=getTable.responseText;
    }
}
getTable.open("GET","tableDate.html",true);
getTable.send();        
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div onClick="loadTable();">Load Table</div>
<div id="tableArea"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the file Ajax is pulling in:

```
<div class="list_holder">
  <table id="list_overview" cellpadding="10" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><span class="sort" data-sort="name">Name</span></th>
        <th><span class="sort" data-sort="term">Term</span></th>
        <th><span class="sort" data-sort="module">Module</span></th>
        <th><span class="sort" data-sort="activity">Activity</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="list">
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Zack Walker</td>
        <td class="term">3</td>
        <td class="module">Body Language</td>
        <td class="activity">None</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Peter Jones</td>
        <td class="term">1</td>
        <td class="module">Body Language</td>
        <td class="activity">All</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Zack Walker</td>
        <td class="term">3</td>
        <td class="module">Helping</td>
        <td class="activity">All</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Is the first `<script` tag like that in your code? Also, there's no reason to not use `$.ajax` if you already have jQuery on the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just guessing here, shouldn't you be initializing the list after you populate the data in your ajax response?

Comment: yes, moved the table init inside the ajax success callback and all works :)

Comment: @dmo You should have updated your question with the solution so other people stumbling across this could have seen how you ended up solving it as the chosen answer didn't include any code.